# How to rename the word from anywhere under my .html files without using File::Find in perl?

Tags: perl

---

Here is my query the following is my directory structure .

```
`-- ka
    |-- ka.html
    `-- ka_tal
        |-- tal_cation
        |   |-- tal_cation.html
        |   `-- ev1
        |       `--ka_ka_tal_tal_cation_v1.html
        |
        `-- ka_tal.html
```

Here every .html files have the word named as tevision i want to rename all words tevision to ev.so i had tried the  following code.But it not works for me.

```
 finddepth(sub {

  return unless -d;

  (my $new = $_) =~ s/tevision/ev/ or return;
  rename $_, $new or warn "Err renaming $_ to $new in $File::Find::dir: $!";
}, ".");
```

How can i rename all words inside .html files using perl?

Comment: Why without using File::Find? File::Find has been a standard part of the Perl distribution for over twenty years. There's no reason to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
my $path = "ka/";
find($path);
sub find{
    my ($s) = @_;
    foreach my $ma (glob "\Q$s\E/*")
    {
      if(-f $ma && $ma =~ m/\.html\z/)
      {
        system('perl', '-i', '-pe', 's/tevision/ev/', '--', $ma);
      }
      elsif(-d $ma)
      {
        find($ma)
      }

    }
}
```

Comment: Use `glob "\Q$s\E/.* \Q$s\E/*"` if you also want to scan "hidden" files and directories.

Comment: @ikegami Can you explain the use of `--` in the above one liner?

Comment: Denotes the ends of options. It makes it so values of `$ma` that start with `-` won't be treated as options. Admittedly, it won't happen in that program (since all paths start with `ka/`), but it's a good habit.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the subroutine that is called by File::Find, the `$_` variable will contain the **name** of the file that has been found. Your code seems to think it will contain the contents of the file. To get the contents of the file, you will need to open the file and read the contents. Then you will need to make your conversions and write the altered contents back to the original file.

This is all far easier using a combination of the Unix `find` command and Perl's command-line options. It probably helps to work out the solution for a single file and then use `find` to execute that command on all of the required files.

```
$ perl -i -pe 's/tevision/ev/' some_file.html
```

This takes a file (some_file.html), opens it and processes the file.

- -i : this writes the converted input back to the original file
- -p : this loops round all the lines in the file. Each one, in turn, is stored in `$_` and the contents of `$_` are printed after each iteration of the loop.
- -e : this is the code you want to run for each line of the file.

We can then put that into a `find` command to get the full behaviour that you want.

```
$ find . -name "*.html" -exec perl -i -pe 's/tevision/ev/' {} \;
```

The following are more efficient because they don't launch as many instances of `perl`:

```
$ find . -name "*.html" -exec perl -i -pe 's/tevision/ev/' {} +   # Requires GNU find

$ find . -name "*.html" -print0 | xargs -0 perl -i -pe 's/tevision/ev/'
```